# Settings app keeps crashing on Meizu M6

Tags: settings, crashes, flyme-os, meizu

When I try to open the Setting app on my Meizu M6 (with Flyme 7.1.1.0G), it stays on for like a half a second and then closes.

Usually when this happens to me, what I do is clear the cache or if that won't help, even the data of the application. So basically, Settings is not working, so go to Settings, Apps, Settings, and clear cache. I hope everyone sees the catch here.

I've tried restarting the phone, but the Settings app still crashes. I've noticed that if I am fast enough, I can get into the submenu of the settings, so I've spent 30 minutes training my fingers to open settings, scroll down, and click Apps in less than half a second. I was lucky and managed to get into Apps (which didn't crash), found Settings app and when I tried to clear the cache, Apps crashed and Settings didn't work either.

What can I do? I would love to avoid a factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can try booting the phone into safe mode and see if the problem persists. If so, then you might have corrupted system files and you'll need to reflash the ROM to fix that.

Comment: Probably a naive question,  but how do you boot in safe mode?

Comment: You can do that by booting the phone normally and getting to the power menu by long pressing the power button and then touching and holding on reboot (or power off icon depending on the vendor) until it prompts to reboot into safe mode, accept the prompt to reboot into safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the solution for your problem but for others like me coming here from a search, my issue seems to be caused by my work profile.

My workaround:

- Swipe up from the bottom of your home screen (launcher) to open your app drawer.
- Tap on the "Work" tab.
- Tap on the "Turn off work apps" button.

My Settings app stopped crashing when my work profile was temporarily disabled.

I tried freezing one app at a time in my work profile (through Shelter), but it still crashes with all user apps frozen. It might be an issue with the actual profile. I recently enabled a lock screen PIN and fingerprint on my main profile, so that may have messed up something with my work profile. I found someone with a similar problem and he said disabling "Use one lock" in the Android security settings fixed his issue, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just have experienced a very similar problem (the Settings app immediately crashes on opening, de-facto making any kind of access to phone settings impossible). Since this is the first hit for such a question on Google, I'll describe my case and the fix here:

The problem in my case was that the Settings app somehow **depends on** the Google app and crashes when the Google app is up-to-date (at the time of writing this). It is certainly the case that my phone's Android version is rather ancient (9) and could be due to some oversight on the manufacturer's side, but this nevertheless is a fairly recent regression and Google will hopefully fix it in the future.

As a **temporary fix**, resetting the Google app to factory via "uninstall" + prohibiting auto-updates for the Google app works.